# Mask first numbers on security number in HTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, kendo-ui, mask

I have a requirement that ask me to mask the social security number's first digits. What would be the best way to achieve this in a ASP.NET with Kendo UI (HTML 5, JQuery, CSS, etc.) ?

**EDIT :** The field is databound. I want it to be masked with "*" in read mode but fully visible in edit mode. Don't worry, those who have the rights to edit it are limited.

Comment: use javascript `.substr()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr see http://jsfiddle.net/XEmC5/

Comment: Is it an input? If so use jQuery